# I'm now getting the following errors on my site and not sure how to proceed

Tags: views, 8, entities, wsod

Started getting the following error on my views admin page after updating to 8.2.0-rc1, have tried searching for related issues with no success as yet. Seeking help from someone better versed in backend drupal than I currently am.

---

The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityMalformedException: The "view" entity cannot have a URI as it does not have an ID in Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity->toUrl() (line 179 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Entity.php). Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityBase->toUrl('edit-form', Array) (Line: 171)
Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity->urlInfo('edit-form', Array) (Line: 408)
Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityBase->urlInfo('edit-form') (Line: 146)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityListBuilder->getDefaultOperations(Object) (Line: 33)
Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\ConfigEntityListBuilder->getDefaultOperations(Object) (Line: 155)
Drupal\views_ui\ViewListBuilder->getDefaultOperations(Object) (Line: 122)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityListBuilder->getOperations(Object) (Line: 203)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityListBuilder->buildOperations(Object) (Line: 185)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityListBuilder->buildRow(Object) (Line: 87)
Drupal\views_ui\ViewListBuilder->buildRow(Object) (Line: 223)
Drupal\views_ui\ViewListBuilder->render() (Line: 22)
Drupal\Core\Entity\Controller\EntityListController->listing('view')
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}() (Line: 574)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 124)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber{closure}()
call_user_func_array(Object, Array) (Line: 139)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 62)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 99)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 78)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 50)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 649)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)

---

Also get a rather large error on the report page that starts with the following - not sure if this info will help or not.

Notice: Undefined index: id in Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\Query\Query->Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\Query{closure}() (line 92 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/Entity/Query/Query.php). Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\Query\Query->Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\Query{closure}(Array, Array)
uasort(Array, Object) (Line: 93)
Drupal\Core\Config\Entity\Query\Query->execute() (Line: 98)

Update: Solved - it was an issue with the group module when trying to update to 8.2.0-beta2 or above. It was since been resolved from within the module and smooth sailing has returned.

Comment: Sorry but it's not possible to debug your site from here

Comment: No worries - I'll edit it to the smaller error I'm currently only getting on my views admin page. It may possibly be responsible for the other issues as well.